# Create mesh from procedural volumetric material 'isosurface'

Tags: modeling, mesh, volumetrics, mathematics, procedural

So [Rich Sedman](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/29586/rich-sedman?tab=profile) wrote [an answer / tutorial](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80296/give-this-mesh-a-uniform-thickness-on-all-the-tubes-and-unions/81396#81396) on how to make a random / organic scaffolding structure using procedural volumtetric materials. He essentially defines an isosurface in math nodes and uses shaders to render them. I would like to take that surface and use it as a mesh, but I cant figure out how.

Does anyone know of a way to turn a volumetric material into a mesh?

Perhaps convert it into a point cloud and then use marching cubes or use metaballs? Can voxel remesher be used on volumetric material?

People have seem to been doing similar stuff, I cant figure out how, but perhaps volumetric material is the wrong way to start:

https://blenderartists.org/t/voxel-remesher-shader-modeling/1197740/4

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6n62SZMC3fo

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oOlwvTmScKg

[How to create a mesh from metaballs which will always work with a Boolean modifier?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40094/how-to-create-a-mesh-from-metaballs-which-will-always-work-with-a-boolean-modifi)

https://www.reddit.com/r/blenderhelp/comments/d6gpmb/mesh_from_volumetric/

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do that with Blender. However, you can try another approach like building the mesh with Sverchok/Animation Node (like OP did in your link) or the Tissue add-on.

Comment: Ok I see, maybe I should adapt my question to how to make an isosurface mesh, regardless of the method?

Comment: Using XYZ math surface from extra objects addon? Parametric, will depend on what you want to do. In particular there is no random in it, afaik

Comment: You should first explore parametric modelling with simple equations (create a cube, create a sphere, create a pyramid...) and work your way up to more complicated things, otherwise you won't understand everything and you will have trouble debugging or expanding your tool

Comment: I agree, I dont understand the basics (within blender at least) yet. Will go this route but will take a few weeks probably with limited time.